# Farthest away and distance in miles between two points

Tags: c#, arraylist, distance

I am using a .DAT file that contains 700 x and y coordinates with a name of the location, I know how to separate the x and the y for each of them, so at the moment each coordinate is separated. So my main point is set up like **USAcamp 50 50** and I need to find the farthest distance away from 50,50 inside my code with the name attached. What is the best formula to use to find this? I also need to find how many miles are between each point and 50,50.

Everything is seperated like this:

```
string usaNames;
double x;
double y;
```

Thanks for any help, I can clarify on things if this is too confusing, I'm learning so everything helps.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest distance between two points is:

> SQRT((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)

Thus do this calculation for all sets of points and find the greatest distance.

As it related to C#, I would create a composite class around C#'s Point class and add the field for the name, then perform the nested for-loop to find the distances.

```
double max = -1;
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1;i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
        // Calculate the distance and set the max if highest
    }
}
```

For more information look at this post: [What is the most efficient way to calculate the maximum distance of two points in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473503/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-calculate-the-maximum-distance-of-two-points-i)